# Android crash from log

Tags: android, logcat, reboot

my android phone have some random reboot. I'm try to figure out what the problem is using adb logcat.
I catch this log exacly before the phone crashes and rebooting, it is possible to get the cause?

This happen also when the phone is on standby.

Log:

```
06-25 11:27:46.630 12828 12828 W nativedumper:FW:  ramdump_framework.c(1920): crashinfo.done not created
06-25 11:27:46.630 12828 12828 D nativedumper:main: core dump collected
06-25 11:27:46.630 12828 12828 I nativedumper:main: Native crash dump collection done.
06-25 11:27:46.630  1230  1399 I BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_enqueue: [background,1,Intent { act=com.sonymobile.crashmonitorsystemservice.DIR_UPDATED flg=0x10 (has extras) },2]
06-25 11:27:46.656  1230  3110 I ActivityManager: Start proc 12894:com.sonymobile.rcahandler/1000 for broadcast com.sonymobile.rcahandler/.RcaHandlerReceiver
06-25 11:27:46.667  3484  3484 I IcingInternalCorpora: Contacts corpus disabled.
06-25 11:27:46.690 12833 12882 I Adreno  : QUALCOMM build                   : 7d18700, I8ee426a9a2
06-25 11:27:46.690 12833 12882 I Adreno  : Build Date                       : 10/07/16
06-25 11:27:46.690 12833 12882 I Adreno  : OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
06-25 11:27:46.690 12833 12882 I Adreno  : Local Branch                     : 
06-25 11:27:46.690 12833 12882 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BR.1.3.6_rb1.6
06-25 11:27:46.690 12833 12882 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : NONE
06-25 11:27:46.690 12833 12882 I Adreno  : Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
06-25 11:27:46.698 12833 12882 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-25 11:27:46.698 12833 12882 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
06-25 11:27:46.722  3484  8562 I Icing   : Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
06-25 11:27:46.740 12894 12894 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/RcaHandler/lib/arm64
06-25 11:27:46.759 12894 12894 I LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package alias:com.sonymobile.dummy
06-25 11:27:46.761 12894 12894 I RcaHandler: Forwarding intent: com.sonymobile.crashmonitorsystemservice.DIR_UPDATED
06-25 11:27:46.767   918   918 I MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ130 from CPU1 to CPU0
06-25 11:27:46.769  1230 12509 I BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_finished: [background,1,Intent { act=com.sonymobile.crashmonitorsystemservice.DIR_UPDATED flg=0x10 (has extras) }]
06-25 11:27:46.783 12894 12907 I RcaHandler: fileName = tlcore_native_03
06-25 11:27:46.793 12894 12907 D RcaHandler: Handle APP-dumpfile with UUID:BF31839D-B47B-BEC2-5512-9FA71984C251-BD082E44 from:NativeDumper named:/data/crashdata/tlcore_native_03
06-25 11:27:46.818  1230  1410 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note/com.socialnmobile.colornote.activity.Main: +577ms (total +2s375ms)
06-25 11:27:46.818  1230  1410 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{7d36e43 u0 com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note/com.socialnmobile.colornote.activity.Main t319} time:3292895
06-25 11:27:46.838 12833 12833 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@16a9798 time:3292915
06-25 11:27:46.921  1230  3110 I MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10101/12009 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@5d92c35org.chromium.content.browser.AudioFocusDelegate@eee28ca
06-25 11:27:46.926  1230  9789 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.customtabs.CustomTabActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2022 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:889 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2501 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2459 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2328 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2323 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:193 
06-25 11:27:46.931   568   568 W SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
06-25 11:27:46.938  1230  2586 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.customtabs.CustomTabActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2022 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:889 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2501 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2459 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2328 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2323 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:193 
06-25 11:27:46.950 12009 12009 I cr_BindingManager: onTrimMemory: level=20, size=0
06-25 11:27:46.969   566   566 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/12324/oom_score_adj; errno=22
06-25 11:27:46.976  1230 12509 I ActivityManager: Process com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process1 (pid 12324) has died
06-25 11:27:46.976  1230 12509 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 12324
06-25 11:27:46.976  1230  1257 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x200000000000 in tid 1257 (batterystats-sy)
06-25 11:27:46.979   463   463 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=1230 uid=1000 gid=1000 tid=1257
06-25 11:27:47.147 12916 12916 D clmlib  : Got activities:0x00000003
06-25 11:27:47.147 12916 12916 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-25 11:27:47.147 12916 12916 F DEBUG   : UUID: 08b8db75-9f82-4c24-b808-142433e4f20e
06-25 11:27:47.147 12916 12916 F DEBUG   : SystemDump: requested
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Sony/F5321/F5321:7.0/34.2.A.2.69/1987453466:user/release-keys'
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   : pid: 1230, tid: 1257, name: batterystats-sy  >>> system_server <<<
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x200000000000
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     x0   00000000ffffffff  x1   0000007f5e9aa880  x2   0000000000000008  x3   0000000000000008
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000008  x6   0000007f7af4a000  x7   0000000000000000
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000000
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     x12  0000000000000000  x13  ffffffffa6b08aca  x14  00049691be000000  x15  003b9aca00000000
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     x16  0000007f79abdee0  x17  0000007f7a89e2b4  x18  0000007f76ff07b0  x19  0000000000000000
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     x20  0000200000000000  x21  0000000000000000  x22  00000000ffffffff  x23  0000007f7713cae0
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     x24  0000000000000028  x25  0000000000000001  x26  0000000070b43890  x27  0000000012c83078
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     x28  0000007f7706a380  x29  0000007f5e9aaa40  x30  0000007f79ab3e54
06-25 11:27:47.148 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     sp   0000007f5e9aaa10  pc   0000007f79ab3e9c  pstate 0000000060000000
06-25 11:27:47.265 12833 12879 D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
06-25 11:27:47.647 12916 12916 F DEBUG   : 
06-25 11:27:47.647 12916 12916 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
06-25 11:27:47.648 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0000000000017e9c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+136)
06-25 11:27:47.648 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00000000000edc9c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+48)
06-25 11:27:47.648 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0000000001f7e310  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x16de000) (android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce+140)
06-25 11:27:47.648 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0000000001f7ff24  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x16de000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+240)
06-25 11:27:47.648 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 0000000001f79730  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x16de000) (android.os.Looper.loop+492)
06-25 11:27:47.648 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 0000000001bdf5d8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x16de000) (android.os.HandlerThread.run+260)
06-25 11:27:47.648 12916 12916 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 0000000000ef1aa4  /system/framework/oat/arm64/services.odex (offset 0xe21000)
06-25 11:27:47.730  3484  8562 I Icing   : Indexing ABFAA1D79229476FC443D3FC9929CC95E6E86B47 from com.android.chrome
06-25 11:27:50.642 12894 12907 I RcaHandler: Saved NATIVE_APP (ID:82e9c5d3-fc21-4492-a36f-420abee2f9cc) to IDD
06-25 11:27:50.643 12894 12907 I RcaHandler: Added entry APP to rca-list
06-25 11:27:50.648   564   564 I iddd    : Uncompress. (com.sonyericsson.idd.probe.android.rca:RcaInfoProbeExtended) 118856 - 914678 bytes
06-25 11:27:50.649   564   564 E iddd-plugins: Max dir size or partition utilization reached. Failed to stat /rca/plugins/rca-extended/rcaep_12: No such file or directory
06-25 11:27:51.255 12916 12916 D clmlib  : Going to use a fd
06-25 11:27:51.256 12916 12916 D clmlib  : Going to use a fd
06-25 11:27:51.256 12916 12916 W clmlib  : To large file to store in rdinfo_log (2309537)
06-25 11:27:51.256 12916 12916 D clmlib  : Going to use a fd
06-25 11:27:51.256 12916 12916 D clmlib  : Restricting length of rdtag:rdinfo_log to: 8192
06-25 11:27:51.257 12916 12916 D clmlib  : Going to use a fd
06-25 11:27:51.258 12916 12916 D clmlib  : Going to use a fd
06-25 11:27:51.261 12916 12916 I clmlib  : Sync file system
06-25 11:27:51.328 12916 12916 I clmlib  : System dump request: pid=1230 (system_server, system_server)
06-25 11:27:51.328 12916 12916 I clmlib  : Reports as: system_server, type=10
06-25 11:27:51.328 12916 12916 D clmlib  : Going to use a fp for sysrq
```

Thanks.

Comment: This might be an interesting problem to solve, _but_ I think if off-topic here. I'm voting to close this question as it is not related to programmig.

Comment: I agree, try other sites, perhaps someone at https://forum.xda-developers.com/ is able and willing to help (first try to find the right Forum for your phone).

Comment: I'll try xda maybe someone can read this locgat logs. Thanks Peter B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-installing Chrome or try another browser. It looks like Chrome has a hiccup here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I try to disable chrome and use firefox but the problem persists